# How to open an app directly from deeplink if app is installed already?

Tags: java, android, deep-linking, appsflyer

I want to open app directly without giving propmt open with browser or open with app.

I followed some links on stackoverflow did exactly what they did but still no luck.

Please help to get it fixed.

```
<activity
            android:name="com.zappfresh.android.Activity.login.SplashActivity"
            android:label="Zappfresh"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:host="zappfresh.onelink.me"
                    android:pathPrefix="/T0HX"
                    android:scheme="https" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Comment: Does this page answer your question? https://developer.android.com/training/app-links

Comment: @JanHeld yeah i checked this doc...but this error is coming "digital assest links file not found at {url}"......but i have placed the assestslink.json file in root folder of my domain